# Receiving a `inconsistent metadata` error when querying a table from a linked server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

```
SELECT * FROM [POSTGRESSQL35W].[Briefs].[public].[planbrief]
```

I've been scratching my head for hours just trying to run the query above. I can successfully retrieve data from certain tables, however, for this particular table it throws the error below. Does anyone know how to circumvent this ?

Also, I already know about the function `OPENQUERY`, which I tried and it still does not work.

```
Msg 7356, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "POSTGRESSQL35W" supplied inconsistent metadata for a column. The column "rewarded" (compile-time ordinal 50) of object ""Briefs"."public"."planbrief"" was reported to have a "DBCOLUMNFLAGS_ISLONG" of 128 at compile time and 0 at run time.
```

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly select the columns (one by one) and then use cast/convert for the ones which cause problems?

Comment: @lptr Yes, that was the first thing I actually tried. Selecting any column in that table throws that same error, whether or not i'm selecting the `rewarded` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue.

Just in case anyone else is having this problem, a workaround is to go to `Start > Search ODBC Data Source Administrator > System DNS > Configure`

Once the pop up window opens, under Options go to `Datasource`.

Then untick `Bools as Char`, apply and save.